# Replace a missing value SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table (SQL Server 2017) on sales of goods in stores, some records have no price.

```
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| year_id | week_number | good_id | store_id | price |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2019    | 6           | 140629  | 2        | 199   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2019    | 8           | 140629  | 2        | NULL  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2017    | 40          | 137233  | 9        | 278   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2017    | 35          | 137233  | 9        | NULL  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2017    | 37          | 137233  | 9        | NULL  |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
```

We would like to replace the missing values according to the following scheme: set the price value to the same as the good with this number (**good_id**) from the same store (store_id), but sold as far as possible in the nearest to the missing value date, for example:

```
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| year_id | week_number | good_id | store_id | price |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2019    | 6           | 140629  | 2        | 199   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2019    | 8           | 140629  | 2        | 199   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2017    | 40          | 137233  | 9        | 278   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2017    | 35          | 137233  | 9        | 278   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2017    | 37          | 137233  | 9        | 278   |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+
```

So far made something like this, but this query contains mutually exclusive conditions, so it does not affect the rows:

```
UPDATE dataset
SET price = p.price
FROM dataset AS p
WHERE good_id = p.good_id
AND store_id = p.store_id
AND price IS NULL
AND p.price IS NOT NULL;
GO
```

Comment: For this type of query, you need to reference the target table twice. `UPDATE t SET t.price = p.price
FROM dataset AS p
INNER JOIN dataset as t
 ON t.good_id = p.good_id
 AND t.store_id = p.store_id
WHERE t.price IS NULL
 AND p.price IS NOT NULL
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply`.  This works if all years have 52 weeks:

```
update d
    set price = d2.price
    from dataset d cross apply
         (select top (1) d2.*
          from dataset d2
          where d2.good_id = d.good_id and
                d2.store_id = d.store_id and
                d2.price is not null
          order by abs( (d2.year_id * 52 + d2.week_id) - (d.year_id * 52 + d.week_id) )
         ) d2
    where d.price is null;
```

The only issue is when the comparisons pass the year boundary and the previous year has 53 weeks.  Depending on how you define years, you can convert the year/week combos in to dates and use direct date comparisons for the difference.